# How to get the same network with QEMU than VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu

I've 2 VMs Debian 9.4 : one working trough VirtualBox  ; the other working trough QEMU. I configured a bridge on my workstation like this :

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap group 1000
ip link set dev tap0 up promisc on
ip addr add 0.0.0.0 dev tap0

#Creating bridge br0 
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set tap0 master br0
echo "0" | tee --append /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/stp_state
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev br0

sysctl net.ipv4.conf.tap0.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.enp6s0.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o enp6s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp6s0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

In VirtualBox network configuration panel I took tap0 as bridge. The VM can go on the WEB, do update of the system, recieve a connection with ssh  and the mean action I expect,  install npm package without PB as example : `npm install color`

I've problem with the QEMU virtual machine that I'm launching with this command :

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda Debian9_amd64_stretch_fr.qcow2 -m 1024 -device e1000,netdev=network0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 -netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

With this virtual machine I can go on the WEB, do update of the system, receive a connection with ssh on the VM but I can not do the mean action I expect,  install npm package. I've got this error message :

```
npm ERR! Invalid argument: family must be 4 or 6
```

You should know I passed many times before to know there is a network problem so is not coming from npm. Is the comparison with the both VM software told me where is coming out.

Thanks

Comment: Use libvirtd and virt-manager to run your VMs. It will take care of virtual networking for you. And save your sanity from having to create those lengthy command lines.

Comment: Easy answer in this case I don't need QEMU and I keep Virtualbox working. How to configure the netdev and device options of QEMU ?